SQL Server copy linked server table to local table as quickly as possible
Currently I'm doing a simple table copy using a linked server:
DELETE FROM [LocalTable]
INSERT INTO [LocalTable] 
    SELECT * FROM [LinkedServer].[LinkedDB].[dbo].[RemoteTable]

It currently takes 1 minute to finish for only 600k rows and I have to run this very frequently. The indexes are different with the local table having 3 and the remote table having 6. Neither have primary/foreign keys. What would be the best way to speed this up as much as possible?
Edit: Here some more info -

400 MB of data, 115 MB of index data
Execution plan show (totals):
16% index insert, 12% sort, 66% table spool, 43% table insert, 15%
remote query.
Local server is SQL server 2008, remote server is 2022


And are you really using SQL server 2008 in the year 2024?

@DaleK 400 MB for data, 115 MB for indexes.
Also execution plan shows (totals): 16% index insert, 12% sort, 66% table spool, 43% table insert, 15% remote query. Not sure why it's over 100%.
And I don't have a choice on the SQL server version, but it's 2008 local and 2016 on the remote server.

SQL Server 2008 has been formally end of life for more than 5 years now. It's hasn't had any updates in that time... not even critical security patches. It's dangerous and irresponsible to still be using it. You may not have a direct say, but you do have a responsibility to push that information up the chain.

If I had it my way it'd be upgraded but unfortunately I have to work with it right now. I will keep pushing for an upgrade though

A TRUNCATE would make more sense than a DELETE, considering you want to delete everything.

insert into xx (tablock) might speed things up a little, what recovery model do you have? Remote querys are always gonna be somewhat slow. You could look into optimizing but not selecting the whole shebang perhaps, or look into log shipping etc

Why do you even need to do this btw? Create a view against the remote table and take some coffee

@ThomA Unfortunately it's the insert that takes the majority of the time, doing a truncate looks to be about to same

@siggemannen There are issues with the domain controller and remote server, so I need to do this for now. Also is there any speed benefit using a view vs querying the linked server directly?

I must admit, with the ancient version, the domain controller issues, etc, this is all starting to sound like an XY Problem, and fundamentally fixing the domain(s?) and software should be the real priority.

Maybe a SYNONYM would make more sense, @siggemannen . Depending on the queries, hopefully the filtering can be offloaded to the remote server.

Is that data date-based, where older data does not change? Perhaps something like DELETE FROM LocalTable WHERE PostedDate >= @Threshold INSERT INTO LocalTable  SELECT * FROM LinkedServer.LinkedDB.dbo.RemoteTable WHERE PostedDate >= @Threshold would limit the amount of data added and deleted. Alternately, if the source has added/modified dates, retrieve the recent data to a temporary staging table and then selectively insert/update the changes. (This does not handle deletes though.)

You might wanna try out replication too. I'd say, performance wise it goes: 1) Log shipping 2) Manual copy a-la what you're doing 3). Replication, but replication can be faster if you don't need to flush everything from scratch. You can also try OPENQUERY or EXEC('select ...') AT RemoteServer to fetch the data, maybe it will be faster, who knows. But yeah, i question why you need to do this so often, sounds like a broken design

I'd suggest a TABLOCK on both source and destination, also disable all indexes, insert and re-enable indexing


What would be the best way to speed this up as much as possible?

Upgrade from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2022.  Honestly that stuff is so old, that I hesitate to suggest anything you might even try.

Some embedded systems need old databases although one can often get around the requirement by using a programmable database proxy. (eg Businesses are not going to replace an expensive machine tool just because it needs an old database.)
Linked servers tend to be slow. Try

writing a program/script to copy the table. Powershell should be adequate.

or

run the process from the SQL2022 server and use Polybase.

